# How can I set an environmental variable with glab (glab-cli)?

Tags: gitlab, glab

I would like to set an environmental variable with `glab`. I don't see the option on `glab ci`. How can I set an environmental variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently under `glab variable`,

Manage GitLab Project and Group Variables

```
USAGE
  glab variable [flags]

ALIASES
  var

CORE COMMANDS
  delete:     Delete a project or group variable
  export:     Export project or group variables.
  get:        get a project or group variable
  list:       List project or group variables
  set:        Create a new project or group variable
  update:     Update an existing project or group variable

FLAGS
  -R, --repo OWNER/REPO   Select another repository using the OWNER/REPO or `GROUP/NAMESPACE/REPO` format or full URL or git URL

INHERITED FLAGS
  --help   Show help for command

LEARN MORE
  Use 'glab <command> <subcommand> --help' for more information about a command.
```